# Choosing between PubSub and CloudRun to send images to Google Functions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to familiarize myself with GCP. I build a simple Android app that can upload photos to Firebase storage.

[image]

Now I want to do some processing on the cloud on the images I have on Firebase.
[image]

I thinking of having some [Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) on the cloud that can take care of the image processing and then store the image to Firebase.

But I am trying to identify what is a good way for my Android app to send photos to the Cloud Functions.

1. Have a PubSub to which Android service can upload photos. The function will listen on the PubSub (using a [PubSub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)) and when an upload message gets queued, the Function can fetch the message and process it. Is PubSub good to work with images?
2. Use[CloudRun for image processing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/image-processing) and content moderation.
3. Store the photos directly on Firebase storage. Once the photos are in the Firebase store, Build a job/listener on the Firebase store ([gcp-storage-events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events)), process the photos, and save it back. However, this option seems to have additional overhead. Also, I want to make sure all images go through the "image processing" before being added to the Firebase store (to enforce something like content moderation). All photos that get saved to Firebase storage must go through a content moderation check. I will discard a photo if the check fails. So this approach doesn't seem to be the cleanest.

I am trying to identify which would be a better approach and the pros and cons between these or is there a better way I can handle this? Can someone help me with it?

Comment: _"Have a PubSub to which Android service can upload photos."_ I don't think pub/sub is a good to use with images (base64 encoded?). How are you planning to use PubSub? Also, it's easier to upload files to storage using Firebase Client libraries from your app directly. You will still have the file in storage even if processing fails.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I did come across it as well, that Firebase may not be good to use for images. I haven't fully explored it yet. That's what I have currently, directly use Firebase client libraries on the app to directly upload to Firebase storage. But it seems redundant to then build a listener on the Firebase storage and again store the file back.

Comment: Option 3 is the most scalable and the most recommended.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Can you share a bit more context on why this is the most scalable/recommended? Especially comparing this against Option 2. I have another App that displays all photos once they are in Firebase storage. That's why I wanted to have a way that only after some content moderation, a photo will get stored in Firebase.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Also I don't wat to store the photo to Firebase if certain checks aren't met.

Comment: Sync processing is not the most recommended for user experience. The best pattern is to upload the pict ASAP. Then perform background processing on the pict (moderation, labelling, resize,...) and store the result (metadata in database (firestore?), valid/resized pict in a final bucket). Eventually remove the pict from the first location not to keep unsafe pict (you can also add lifecycle to remove automatically pict from storage).

Comment: Async process allows you to stack the events for processing in PubSub and unstack them at your rythm. If your Cloud Run service is saturated you will continue to allow users to upload picts, only the post processing is delayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252305/discussion-between-syncmaster-and-guillaume-blaquiere).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think it will helpful for future visitors to see see the information in your comments, as an answer.